# exfat I installed the both exfat packages on Ubuntu 15.04 though I receive an error message while inserting the SD-card

Tags: mount, 15.04, exfat

As I alredy said I installed the fuse-exfat driver packages in Ubuntu 15.04 though I get an error message while inserting a SanDisk 64 GB SDXC UHS-II memeory card. Card is recognized as 63 GB storage device. The error message is:

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/*******/1CA5-DC81: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/*******/1CA5-DC81"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout:`FUSE exfat 1.1.0
'
stderr: `ERROR: fsync failed: Input/output error.

The card is readable under Windows. And as a suplus I can use a 128 GB USB 3 memory stick without problems on the Linux machine.

Though it should be possible to get that card working I can't. Same behaviour on two systems.

I'd appreciate if someone has suggestions why this doesn't work.

Thanks.

'

Comment: Ok, I checked this issue with the SanDisk support and they asked me whether the card reader worked with other cards. So I checked a SanDisk SDHC Extreme Pro 32 GB 45MB/s  and  a SanDisk SDXC Extreme Pro 128 GB UHS-I 95MB/s and both worked flawless.  If this behaviour is identical for a second card reader, the SanDisk support said this may be an indication that the UHS-II card is not workin properly and should be replaced.